# Group_by, summarise reactivity not working in R Shiny

Tags: shiny, group-by, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity, summarize

Reactivity is working everywhere else in my app, but when I try to create a summary statistic table the table returns the name of the variable selected instead of the summary statistic:

```
ui <- selectInput('summary_metric', 'Select Metric', choices = c('height', 'weight'))
      tableOuput('summary_table')

server <- function(input, output) {
      output$summary_table <- renderTable({ data %>% group_by(Age_Group) %>% 
                                                     summarise(min = min(input$summary_metric),
                                                               median = median(weight))})
```

Returns a table that reads:

| Age_Group | min | median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18-29 | weight | 170 |
| 30-39 | weight | 180 |
| 40-49 | weight | 190 |

when 'weight' is selected in the UI and toggles to 'height' in the min column when 'height' is selected in the UI. So instead of calculating the minimum, it is just returning the variable name. Any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Comment: `input$summary_metric` is just a character. Try with the `.data` pronoun, i.e. do `min(.data[[input$summary_metric]])`. See e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-dplyr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to return the output of an if statement to use as a filter in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705136/is-it-possible-to-return-the-output-of-an-if-statement-to-use-as-a-filter-in-shi)